# Angular2 lazy load styles/css or change the stylesUrl on the fly ?

Tags: angular

Just wondering if there is any way of lazy loading styles in a component or maybe dynamically injecting some styles or changing the stylesUrls?

Let's say this is my component :

```
@Component(
    {
        selector   : 'my-component' ,
        template   : 'some stuff',
        styleUrls : [aVariableHereThatReturnsTheUrl]
    }
)

export class MyComponent{

    private aVariableHereThatReturnsTheUrl = 'app/src/style/style.css';
}
```

Is this possible at all ?

Comment: I don't think you can dynamic the styleUrls because you can not access properties inside @Component. Also, you can see: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/25/styling-angular-2-components.html for three ways to associate CSS styles.

Comment: What would you achieve, depending on a button click or dropdown choice, load another stylesheet? Because you can lazy load your component and associate the css to your component.